# Rails Terminal tasks hang on use, while equivalent rake task works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

Recently started a Rails project being built for school (note I'm relatively new to Rails): Rails 6.1.4.4, Ruby 2.7.5, generated with the new Rails app command. You can find it here: https://github.com/horaciovelvetine/horaciovelvetine/tree/horaciovelvetine/issue51

While working on the project I've been running my rake tasks in the terminal like normal with the following:
`rails db:migrate, rails db:setup, rails console, etc....`

When I came back to work on the project today, I started off by bundle updating, then attempted to use `rails console` only for the terminal to hang and never bring my into the pry console I was trying to. After a few more attempts I figured I'd give `rake console` a shot, and it worked, and is continuing to do so. However the similar rails task seems to be continually hanging (I have to exit w/ ctrl+c, or quit terminal and try again).

Is this any tell tale symptom of a larger issue I have unknowingly caused? I prefer understanding, and this mystery has me scratching my head, and failing to find anything specific/helpful elsewhere.

I'm not sure what else would be helpful to know. Happy to provide more info as needed!

Thanks for the time/thought in advance!!

Comment: Try running `spring stop`.

Comment: Wow. Thank you @max, fixed it right up. I will go figure out why spring does that, thank you!